# How fill and autoresized in splitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, splitcontainer

I have filled splitcontainer.

legend for image:

1. - SplitContainer
2. - ListViews
3. - Spliter

Need:
blue lines show what to do with a ListView.

[image]

Comment: @ Simply denis - You have 42 questions to select answers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the property [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) to [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle.aspx)

Comment: I set all split and listview the property Dock Fill

Comment: @simply denis who's the listbox parent ? ensure is the panel divided by the splitter

Comment: Parent listbox1 splitterChild.Panel1 and listbox2 splitterChild.Panel2. And splitterParent.Panel1 is parent splitterChild.

Comment: try set the `Dock` property to `Fill` using **VisualStudio Designer**